# Преобразовать XML файл с помощью XSLT и записать в другой XML

Tags: java, xml, xslt

Помогите разобраться, никак до меня не доходит. Есть XML документ("1.xml"), выглядит так:

```
<entries>
    <entry>
        <field>1</field>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <field>2</field>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <field>3</field>
    </entry>
    
</entries>
```

Нужно из него, посредством xslt сделать, чтобы выглядело так:

```
<entries>
<entry field="значение поля field">
...
<entry field="значение поля field">
</entries>
```

Вот мой XSLT("red.xslt") файл:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="entries">
        <entries>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </entries>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="entry">
        <entry>
            <xsl:for-each select="*">
                <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
                    <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </entry>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Пытаюсь написать метод, который будет использовать исходный XML и XSLT и создавать новый XML, который уже с нужной разметкой:

```
public static void transformationXML(){
        try {
            File stylesheet = new File("red.xslt");
            DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document document = builder.parse("1.xml");

            StreamResult file = new StreamResult(new File("2.xml"));
            StreamSource stylesource = new StreamSource(stylesheet);
            Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
            DOMSource source = new DOMSource(document);
            transformer.transform(stylesource,file);



        }catch (ParserConfigurationException | SAXException | IOException | TransformerConfigurationException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (TransformerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Как вы уже поняли, ничего не выходит. Пожалуйста, подскажите как это реализовать.

P.S. Пытался описать ситуацию максимально наглядно (и понятно), чтобы не возникало лишних вопросов. Спасибо;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот ответ на ваш вопрос в комментариях, как правильно делать отступ после пролога XML.

Вам просто нужно добавить следующую строку кода:

```
xformer.setOutputProperty("http://www.oracle.com/xml/is-standalone", "yes");
```

Answer (score 0):

Вообщем разобрался, прилагаю код, может кому нибудь будет полезным!

```
public static void xsl(String inFilename, String outFilename, String xslFilename) {
    try {
        TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();

        Templates template = factory.newTemplates(new StreamSource(new FileInputStream(xslFilename)));

        Transformer xformer = template.newTransformer();
        xformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
        xformer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "4");

        Source source = new StreamSource(new FileInputStream(inFilename));
        Result result = new StreamResult(new FileOutputStream(outFilename));

        xformer.transform(source, result);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Полученный XML в результате выполнения метода:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entries>
    <entry field="1"/>
    <entry field="2"/>
    <entry field="3"/>
    <entry field="4"/>
    <entry field="5"/>
</entries>
```

Comment: Один проблемс, при создании нового XML, рут-тэг начинается с 1 строки и получается что то типо этого: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><entries>